# Setting up maven support for eclipse liferay 6.2

Tags: maven, liferay, maven-3, maven-plugin, liferay-6.2

I am trying to generate maven archetypes for liferay 6.2 using below steps:

1. liferay-maven-plugin downloaded and generated ant install -- done
2. liferay-maven-support-6.2.10.15 downloaded and trying to run mvn install but giving below error:

Can any one help me out?

Log:

```
     Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: liferay-e
     xt-archetype:6.2.10.15
     Parameter: groupId, Value: archetype.it
     Parameter: artifactId, Value: default
     Parameter: version, Value: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
     Parameter: package, Value: build.archetype
     Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: build/archetype
     Parameter: version, Value: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    Parameter: package, Value: build.archetype
    Parameter: groupId, Value: archetype.it
    Parameter: artifactId, Value: default

    project created from Archetype in dir: C:\liferay_tomcat\liferay6.2\Maven\liferay-maven-support-6.2.10.15\archetypes\liferay-ext-     archetype\target\test-classes\projects\default\project\default

     Comparing generated project with reference content:            C:\liferay_tomcat\liferay6.2\Maven\liferay-maven-support-6.2.10.15\archetypes\liferay-ext-archetype\target\test-classes\projects\default\reference
     Contents of file default-ext\pom.xml are not equal
     Contents of file default-ext\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\liferay-plugin-package.properties are not equal
         Contents of file default-ext\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml are not equal
      Contents of file default-ext-impl\pom.xml are not equal
         Contents of file default-ext-lib-global\pom.xml are not equal
        Contents of file default-ext-lib-portal\pom.xml are not equal
        Contents of file default-ext-service\pom.xml are not equal
        Contents of file default-ext-util-bridges\pom.xml are not equal
        Contents of file default-ext-util-java\pom.xml are not equal
        Contents of file default-ext-util-taglib\pom.xml are not equal
          Contents of file default-ext-web\pom.xml are not equal
       Contents of file default-ext-web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\liferay-portl et-ext.xml are not equal
     Contents of file default-ext-web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\portlet-ext.xml are not equal


       Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project liferay-ext-archetype:

       Archetype IT 'default' failed: Some content are not equals
-> [Help 1]

        To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
```

Comment: Could you re-validate version numbers for both portal and maven artifacts as well as if both are either CE or EE?

Comment: Thansk Shivam,  Liferay 6.2.10.15 EE and maven support downloaded from Git Tags of version 6.2.10.15

Comment: Will add in as answer for future references!

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers for both portal and maven artifacts should be checked and also if both are either CE or EE. Mismatched versions can often lead to conflicts when installing artifacts.